# How to automate a commit in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, batch-file, tortoisesvn, commit

I need to add a batch line in my script that make me the opportunity to launch a commit automatically.

So, I don't need to click-right after each change on file and select SVN commit:
I putted the line below but the commit command didn't launch automatically:

```
svn commit -m "Ok." %WORKING_COPY%
```

What's wrong, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseSVN Help, Appendix D. "Automating TortoiseSVN" part, ["D.1. TortoiseSVN Commands" topic](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html#tsvn-automation-basics)

> The TortoiseSVN GUI program is called TortoiseProc.exe. All commands
>   are specified with the parameter /command:abcd where abcd is the
>   required command name. Most of these commands need at least one path
>   argument, which is given with /path:"some\path". In the following
>   table the command refers to the /command:abcd parameter and the path
>   refers to the /path:"some\path" parameter.
>
> Since some of the commands can take a list of target paths (e.g.
>   committing several specific files) the /path parameter can take
>   several paths, separated by a * character.

and

> `:commit` Opens the commit dialog. The `/path` specifies the target
>   directory or the list of files to commit. You can also specify the
>   `/logmsg` switch to pass a predefined log message to the commit
>   dialog. Or, if you don't want to pass the log message on the command
>   line, use `/logmsgfile:path`, where path points to a file containing
>   the log message. To pre-fill the bug ID box (in case you've set up
>   integration with bug trackers properly), you can use the `/bugid:"the
>   bug id here"` to do that.

I.e - you'll  see commit-dialog, but only once

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are trying to do here is fundamentally ill-advised.

Simply right click on the root folder of your working copies, and you can commit all (or some) of the files you have changed in one dialog.

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN is GUI-only and doesn't provide a command-line `svn` executable. You need to install a separate command-line Subversion client for Windows, such as this one: http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/